# XmlDocument CreateElement without xmlns under a prefixed element

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces, xmldocument, prefix

I'm trying to compose a SOAP request to ebay FindingAPI web service by using C# XmlDocument class in the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = (XmlElement)doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("soap", "Envelope", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"));
root.SetAttribute("xmlns", "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services");
XmlElement header = (XmlElement)root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("soap", "Header", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"));
XmlElement body = (XmlElement)root.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("soap", "Body", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"));
XmlElement request = (XmlElement)body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("findItemsByKeywordsRequest"));
XmlElement param = (XmlElement)request.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("keywords"));
param.InnerText = "harry potter phoenix";
```

And, the XML output of above code is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header />
    <soap:Body>
        <findItemsByKeywordsRequest xmlns="">
            <keywords>harry potter phoenix</keywords>
        </findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

However, this XML can't be recognized by the server because of the extra xmlns="" attribute in the findItemsByKeywordsRequest element. The desired XML output should be as below:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services">
    <soap:Header/>
    <soap:Body>
        <findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
            <keywords>harry potter phoenix</keywords>
        </findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Does anyone know what is the problem of my code and please give me some hints. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because your document has default namespace declared in the most outer element you have to repeat that namespace on every child element to avoid adding additional empty one.

Change `request` and `param` elements declaration to contain `"http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"` namespace

```
XmlElement request = (XmlElement)body.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("findItemsByKeywordsRequest", "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"));
XmlElement param = (XmlElement)request.AppendChild(doc.CreateElement("keywords", "http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services"));
```

With these changes your code produces following XML:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns="http://www.ebay.com/marketplace/search/v1/services" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <soap:Header />
    <soap:Body>
        <findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
            <keywords>harry potter phoenix</keywords>
        </findItemsByKeywordsRequest>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```