# how to delete Attribute in Xml

Tags: xml, vb.net

Xml struture

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <mm7:id xmlns:mm7="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" mustUnderstand="1">1234</mm7:id>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <SubmitReq>
            <number xmlns="">5674</number>
        </SubmitReq>
    </soap-env:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Coding

```
Dim bodychild As XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("SubmitReq", "http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/Specs/archive/23_series/23.140/schema/REL-5-MM7-1-2")
        soapBody.AppendChild(bodychild)
        Dim numberAs XmlElement = _xmlRequest.CreateElement("number")
        number.InnerText = "5674"
        bodychild.AppendChild(number)
```

How to delete xmlns="" , I got try using RemoveAttribute and RemoveAttributeAt method but remove nothing. Isn't can remove it?

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572111/xmldocument-createelement-without-xmlns-under-a-prefixed-element) I believe has an answer - because you're adding `number` without a namespace, it's assumed you *don't* intend it to be in the namespace of its parent. Because you don't specify a namespace, the rules of XML dictate that it has to be in the empty namespace, which the document specifies for you.

You should be able to fix it by explicitly specifying the same namespace as `SubmitReq` when you create it.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was exactly the problem I had. I didn't notice that 'xmlns' could be 'xml NameSpace'!

Answer (score 0):

To remove an attribute, you can use the `node.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem` and pass the name of the attribute you want to remove as parameter and the attribute will be removed.

Comment: I try this coding number.Attributes.RemoveNamedItem("xmlns") aslo same can't delete it