# Need help to convert namespace code from XmlWriter to XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument, xmlwriter

for two hours I try now to translate 4 lines of old code with XmlWriter to XmlDocument, but I fail big time! ;(

```
XmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();
XmlWriter.WriteStartElement("document", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "urn:hl7-org:v3 GUDIDSPL.xsd");
```

The lines I have:

```
 XmlDeclaration xmlDeclaration = XmlDocument.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
 XmlElement root = XmlDocument.CreateElement(string.Empty, "document", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
 XmlDocument.AppendChild(root);
 XmlDocument.InsertBefore(xmlDeclaration, root);
```

This is the only thing that works, every peace of code after that, that I tried failed.
I dont get the namespaces 100% correct!
One reason is that "SetAttribute", don't offer a prefix parameter.

I hope you can help.

Kind regards

### Follow up issue:

I implement the code postet by "har07", which works great!
But I have different issue now.

The output should look like this:

```
< document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 GUDIDSPL.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<id root="1fed661f-e015-4ea9-95e5-7cf293cd0517" />
<code code="C101716" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.26.1.1" />
<effectiveTime xsi:type="TS" value="20160212" />
```

But it look like this:

```
< document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 GUDIDSPL.xsd" xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<id root="6c4bb64e-d652-4fe6-80f1-8599196719d0" xmlns="" />
<code code="C101716" codeSystem="2.16.840.1.113883.3.26.1.1" xmlns="" />
<effectiveTime xsi:type="TS" value="20160212" xmlns="" />
```

My create element code generates always this empty xmlns tags.
I added to my namespaceManager ("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

Comment: If you dont have to use Xml try to convert values to a JSON data

Comment: As a matter of code hygiene, don't call your `XmlDocument` instance `XmlDocument`, i.e. avoid `XmlDocument XmlDocument = new XmlDocument();`. This is visually confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Using `SetAttribute()`, you can directly specify the prefix and the attribute local name as the first argument :</s>

```
....
XmlElement root = XmlDocument.CreateElement(string.Empty, "document", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
root.SetAttribute("xsi:schemaLocation", "urn:hl7-org:v3 GUDIDSPL.xsd");
....
```

Another option would be using a newer API, [`XDocument`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), instead of `XmlDocument` :

```
XNamespace d = "urn:hl7-org:v3";
XNamespace xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
var doc = 
    new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
        new XElement(d + "document",  //create root element in default namespace
            new XAttribute("xmlns", d.ToString()), //add default namespace declaration
            new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", xsi.ToString()), //add xsi namespace declaration
            new XAttribute(xsi + "schemaLocation", "urn:hl7-org:v3 GUDIDSPL.xsd") //add xsi:schemaLocation attribute
        )
    );
```

**UPDATE :**

Should've used `SetAttribute()` overload that accept namespace uri to define attribute in namespace i.e `xsi:schemaLocation` :

```
....
XmlElement root = XmlDocument.CreateElement(string.Empty, "document", "urn:hl7-org:v3");
root.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
root.SetAttribute("schemaLocation", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "urn:hl7-org:v3 GUDIDSPL.xsd");
....
```

Comment: Worked great, except (For what ever reason!?) the "xsi:" before scemaLocation is missing! ;(

Comment: @SharpNoiZy my bad, check the **UPDATE** section

Comment: Hi, can you maybe help me through a follow up issue? See my update.

Comment: @SharpNoiZy [XmlDocument CreateElement without xmlns under a prefixed element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572111/xmldocument-createelement-without-xmlns-under-a-prefixed-element)

Comment: Thx, I can try that, but our most outer element is "document" and that is not prefixt.

Comment: @SharpNoiZy the problem there is not in the prefix actually, it is in having *default namespace* (namespace declared without prefix i.e `xmlns="...."`) which your desired XML output happen to have too